# Ubuntu persistent-live USB apps not launching

Tags: 18.04, live-usb

So I have this USB stick with Ubuntu 18.04.4 installed. It works fine to boot from and the persistence seems to work - I can save files fine. Also the pre-installed programs such as Firefox seems to work fine - it launches every time and remembers my logins and such.

The problem arises when I try to install other apps such as Atom, Discord and Spotify. I install them from the Ubuntu software centre, and they work just fine in that session. Whenever I reboot they stop launching. I have given them all available permissions and such.

I used this https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/14912/create-a-persistent-bootable-ubuntu-usb-flash-drive/ guide when creating the USB.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Most application programs can be installed so that they work and persist in a persistent live system. But there are exceptions: the linux kernel cannot be upgraded as well as hardware drivers that belong to the linux kernel, because they are started before the system for persistence is activated. Some application programs do not work out of the box, for example the SSH server (when installed via openssh-server) because ssh wants a real password to log in.

Comment: If you **create a second user ID with a normal password**, you can log in as that user and then log in remotely into your SSH server from other computers into the persistent live system. Maybe the same method will also work with Atom, Discord and Spotify. At least think there is a fair chance, so I suggest that you try it. It is rather easy to first install `gnome-system-tools` and then run `users-admin` to create the second user.

Comment: Maybe you must add this second user ID to the group `sudo` manually: Let us say you add the user `nik`. Edit the file `/etc/group` so that the line starting with `sudo` becomes `sudo:x:27:ubuntu,nik` -- The number might not be 27 and the default username might be kubuntu or lubuntu ...; keep the number and the default username, whatever it is. You should only add a comma and the name of the user ID  that you created.